# How can I insert a new line inbetween two of the same matching char (specific pattern)?

Tags: regex, variables, sed

I have token's in files as such

```
[test][test2][test3]
```

sometimes, if tokens are broken as such

```
[test][test2][test3]ad[te[[[]]]][]]]
```

Only the innermost valid token is read, any unclosed token is treated as a comment and skipped.

So out of the above

```
[test]
[test2]
[test3]
```

are valid tokens
out of the rest, there are only 2 other valid token's which are empty.

Now... what I'd like to do is parse a file using sed.  I have 90% of the parsing done already.  However, I'm stuck on a broken token problem.

Here's my batch script if your curious how the whole process is currently working:

```
echo off
REM s/\][^]]*/&\n/g doesn't work right
REM to remove [[ and ]] s/\][^]]*/&\n/g; s/\[[^[]*/&\n/g
REM to split up ][
for /f %%a in ('dir /b *.txt') do sed -e "s/\]\[/\]\n\[/g" %%~na.txt > %%~na.out
REM remove tabs, split up lines around [ and ]
for /f %%a in ('dir /b *.out') do sed -r "s/\t//g;s/([^]].+)\[/\1\n[/g;s/\]([^[].+)$/]\n\1/g" %%~na.out > %%~na.out2
REM remove all blanklines
for /f %%a in ('dir /b *.out2') do sed -e "s/^ *//; s/ *$//; /^$/d; s/\r//; /^\s*$/d" %%~na.out2 > %%~na.out3
REM cleanup
REM erase *.txt
REM ren *.out3 *.txt
REM erase *.out
echo on
```

**SPECIFIC PROBLEM I'm currently trying to resolve**:
**How can I split off say** `[somedata]]]]sometext` (regardless of how many ]'s I have ).
into

```
[somedata]
]
]
]
sometext
```

and `[[[[[somedata]` (notice the # of brackets shouldn't matter)

```
[
[
[
[
[somedata]
```

Here's real sample data I'm working with

```
item_gloves

[OBJECT:ITEM]

###test###
    [ITEM_GLOVES:ITEM_GLOVES_GAUNTLETS]###test###
[NAME:gauntlet:gauntlets]
###test###[ARMORLEVEL:2][[[]][
[UPSTEP:1][[
###test###[SHAPED]
]][LAYER:ARMOR]###test######test###
[COVERAGE:100]
]][LAYER_SIZE:20]][
[LAYER_PERMIT:15]
[MATERIAL_SIZE:2]
[SCALED]
[BARRED]
[METAL]
[LEATHER]
[HARD]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `grep` with an extended regular expression (`-E`):

```
grep -oE  '\[[^][]+\]' <<< "[test][test2][test3]ad[te[[[]]]][]]]"
```

Output:

```
[test]
[test2]
[test3]
```

Comment: while that is a great solution for a different problem I'm trying to solve, I was trying to keep the non token data as well.  In other words, i'm not trying to REMOVE any data.  I'm merely trying to insert newlines.  I have a need for the data that is outside of token's as well and in the sample output, I kept that data.  This solution MIGHT work if it moved each [token] to a new line while maintaining the rest of the non token data.

Comment: the non token data is used for signature information of the file for patching, as well as the first line being a non token that is important when the file is read.  As I said, it's a great solution for a DIFFERENT problem, just not this one.  This would do what you did, but be a workable solution in my setup: sed -e "s/\[[^][]*\]/\n&\n/g"

Comment: Not if I got it. Need to go sleep for today. Will have a look tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a newline before every opening square bracket and after every closing bracket, with this tiny **sed** script:

```
sed 's/\[/\n[/g;s/\]/]\n/g' your_input_file
```

And if you want to remove the empty lines that are going to be created from the above script, just chain another **sed** command to delete empty lines:

```
sed 's/\[/\n[/g;s/\]/]\n/g' your_input_file | sed '/^$/d'
```

The output the above generates on `[test][test2][test3]ad[te[[[]]]][]]]` is the following:

```
[test]
[test2]
[test3]
ad
[te
[
[
[]
]
]
]
[]
]
]
```

So I am not sure I understand your question properly, but if you want to keep only the well-balanced tokens, you can further **sed** it:

```
sed 's/\[/\n[/g;s/\]/]\n/g' your_input_file | sed '/^\[.*\]$/!d'
```

And the output is then finally:

```
[test]
[test2]
[test3]
[]
[]
```

Okay, but if this is what you want, and if it is guaranteed that no such token crosses newline boundaries, then you could go for a very simple solution with `grep -o`, catching all tokens made of an opening square bracket followed by an arbitrary number of non-bracket characters, and then a closing square bracket:

```
grep -o '\[[^][]*\]' your_input_file
```

Output:

```
[test]
[test2]
[test3]
[]
[]
```